# How to rotate an image with a slider in PyQt5 while keeping it centered?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, geometry, rotation

I want to rotate an image (`dial.png`) by one degree without moving it from its center position using PyQt5. However, despite my best efforts, the image does not stay centered and moves chaotically when rotated. The image should rotate by one degree each time the QSlider value changes.

Below is the code I am currently using to create the label that contains the image to be rotated:

```
        self.dial = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.dial.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 500, 440))
        self.dial.setText("")
        self.dial.setObjectName("dial")
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("dial.png")
        self.dial.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
```

I have not been able to find a solution that meets my requirements. Any ideas or starting points would be greatly appreciated.

```
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(920, 620)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(920, 620))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(920, 620))
```

This is the `dial.png`:

[image: dial.png]

Comment: A good starting point would be to use an image that is actually centered. Other than that, we don't know *how* you're rotating it, you're just showing the code to create the label (and the code about the window is completely irrelevant and useless). Besides, I sincerely hope that you're not trying to edit a file generated with pyuic (read more about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if your code was correct, but even if it was, the chaotic movement you mentioned would still exist because the PNG image is not properly centered, as you can see below:

[image: cp]

and of course a computer program would utilize the actual center of an image rather than the center of human logic.

With that being said, here is one possible way to accomplish what you have asked, including enough comments to help you understand the logic:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QSlider, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

# Define a class that inherits from QMainWindow
class ImageRotator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, image_path):
        # Call the __init__ method of the QMainWindow class to initialize the basic functionality of the main window
        super().__init__()

        # Load the image from the given image path
        self.image = QPixmap(image_path)

        # Create a QLabel to display the image
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setPixmap(self.image)
        # Set the alignment of the label to center
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        # Create a QSlider to control the rotation
        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        # Set the minimum and maximum values of the slider to 0 and 360 degrees, respectively
        self.slider.setMinimum(0)
        self.slider.setMaximum(360)
        # Set the initial value of the slider to 0 degrees
        self.slider.setValue(0)

        # Connect the valueChanged signal of the slider to the rotate_image method
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.rotate_image)

        # Create a QVBoxLayout to hold the QLabel and QSlider
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

        # Create a QWidget to hold the QVBoxLayout
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        # Set the QWidget as the central widget of the QMainWindow
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        # Show the QMainWindow
        self.show()

    def rotate_image(self, angle):
        # Create a QTransform object that will rotate the image around its center point by the given angle
        transform = QTransform().rotate(angle)
        # Apply the transformation to the image and create a new QPixmap object
        rotated_image = self.image.transformed(transform, Qt.SmoothTransformation)
        # Set the rotated image as the pixmap of the QLabel
        self.label.setPixmap(rotated_image)

# Create a QApplication object
app = QApplication([])
# Create an instance of the ImageRotator class with the "dial.png" image file
window = ImageRotator("dial.png")
# Start the QApplication
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I noticed last night that there is a problem with the positioning of the center in ArtBoard, today I solved it and after seeing your comment. Have a nice day!